# How to generate a word document of your my site?

Tags: my-site, word, office-integration, mysite

We will use My sites to generate CV's in Microsoft Word. Any tips on how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way for achieving this. You can achieve this using

1. Create a template file (dotx) file which specifies how the document should look like. You can add controls and specify the field names/image/style etc
2. Create a timer job which runs every day
3. Inside the timer job create logic to generate document using the template files. You can either use Open Office XML SDK or you can use Microsoft Office Interop's

Comment: Hi Amal. Do you know about any good samples for this ?

Comment: You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx as a starting point.